Why does my PHP file return a 404 error when using fetch in my HTML file?
I'm working on a web project where I need to send data from an HTML file to a PHP file using fetch. My project structure is as follows:
Football-Manager-Analysis/
├── templates/
│   └── index.html
├── importData.PHP
├── app.py

My index.html contains the following JavaScript code to send data to importData.PHP:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scouting and Transfer Market Analysis Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Scouting and Transfer Market Analysis Tool</h1>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".html">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button onclick="loadFile()">Load Data</button>
            <button onclick="runData()">Run Data</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tableContainer"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function loadFile() {
            const input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            const file = input.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const doc = parser.parseFromString(e.target.result, 'text/html');
                const table = doc.querySelector('table');
                document.getElementById('tableContainer').innerHTML = table.outerHTML;
            };

            if (file) {
                reader.readAsText(file);
            } else {
                alert('Please select a file.');
            }
        }

        function runData() {
            const table = document.querySelector('#tableContainer table');
            if (!table) {
                alert('No data loaded. Please load data first.');
                return;
            }

            const data = extractTableData(table);
            sendDataToServer(data);
        }

        function extractTableData(table) {
            const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
            const data = [];
            
            rows.forEach(row => {
                const cells = row.querySelectorAll('th, td');
                const rowData = [];
                
                cells.forEach(cell => {
                    rowData.push(cell.textContent);
                });
                
                data.push(rowData);
            });

            return data;
        }

        function sendDataToServer(data) {
            fetch('../importData.PHP', {  // Adjusted to use a relative path
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ tableData: data })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                alert('Data successfully sent to the server');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                alert('An error occurred while sending data to the server');
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

However, when I try to send the data, I get a 404 error:
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2024 00:14:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2024 00:14:42] "POST /importData.PHP HTTP/1.1" 404 - 
I'm running my server from the Football-Manager-Analysis directory. The PHP file is located in the root directory of the project, one level up from the templates folder where index.html is located.
I’ve verified the file’s existence and permissions, and I’m using a relative path. What could be causing this 404 error, and how can I resolve it?

Does an absolute path work? Are you using any back-end frameworks?

javascript will not work with ../  url . your importData.PHP should be publicly accessible and use that url for request.

what is the url  you are using to access index.html file

Is this a problem with JS or PHP? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Have you tried fetch('./../importData.php', {   (added an extra ./). The first ./ points to the current directory, ../ moves one directory up, importData.php is the php file you want to use. Also, use lowercase php in both your code and file

If you use fetch to load data, use full path starting from http://yourpath.com/yourFile.php.
